# How do I turn off or temporarily suspend keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, safari, google-chrome, shortcut

I'm using the site ShorcutFoo to drill keyboard shortcuts for Pro Tools on my Mac.

My problem is that entering a shortcut such as **Command+D** in a practice session naturally conflicts with the internet browser's own responsiveness to those key combinations. So if I try to hit **Command+W** for the correct answer in a Pro Tools shortcut drill, it will instead just close the browser window.

How can I turn off or suspend shortcuts when using a site like this for practice?

Comment: Just out of curiosity...is this Pro Tools for Mac?  I would be surprised that they're using key combinations that's already assigned to macOS.

Comment: Yes indeed, Pro Tools for Mac. I edited my comment b/c I think I used the example of Command+R erroneously. Other commands such as Command+D (duplicates region) and Command+F (fades dialogue) work in Pro Tools, but conflict with ShortcutFoo in-browser.